# Identifying component rootview viewname

Tags: sapui5

Imagine a component with a root view like so:

```
rootView: 'myapp.view.App'
```

The app view looks like this:

```
<mvc:View 
    xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc" 
    xmlns:core="sap.ui.core" 
    xmlns="sap.m" 
    controllerName="myapp.controller.App" 
    displayBlock="true">
    <App id="myapp">
        <mvc:XMLView id="page1" viewName="myapp.view.Page1" />
    </App>
</mvc:View>
```

As you can see there is a controller set up for this view. The view `myapp.view.Page1` is another XML view, has a controller of its own and contains a `sap.m.Page` control.

This `Page1` controller cannot access any controls *without* specifying `__xmlview0--` in front of the Id. I know it's in a view, because the `App` is in a view. `createId` will create something relative to the current controller, so it will return `__xmlview0--page1`.

For instance, I can get the app from my `myapp.controller.Page`, but I have to access using the view name too. The same goes for my pages. Navigating to a new page in the app looks like this:

```
var app = this.byId('__xmlview0--myapp');
app.to('__xmlview0--page1');
```

`this.createId('myapp')` will give me `__xmlview0--page1--myapp`.

I also tried getting the component itself out `this.getOwnerComponent()` and use the `createId` and `getId` methods, but this leaves me with `__component0` instead of `__xmlview0`, so that's a no-go too.

#### edit

Not a super clear story. Maybe this will go you some visuals:

```
-Component.js
    - App.view.xml <App id="myapp"></App>
          - Page1.view.xml <Page id="page1"></Page>
    - App.controller.js
    - Page1.controller.js
          //byId uses createId. 
          //myapp has id __xmlview0--myapp
          this.createId('myapp') = __xmlview0--page1--myapp
          this.getView().createId('myapp') = __xmlview0--page1--myapp
          this.getOwnerComponent().byId('myapp') = __component0--myapp
          this.getOwnerComponent().getView() is not a function
```

How do I determine through my controllers to add `__xmlview0`? Which `createId` method do I use? Is my rootView wrong and is there a more efficient way? How do I get `myapp` out of the component?

Comment: Did you try this.getView().byId() in your controller? This handles proper prefixing for you.

Comment: Yeah, but it gets '__xmlview0--page1--myapp'. Myapp is not in the current view but in the parent one which is the problem.

Comment: @TimGerlach by the way. `byId` uses `createId`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are using the component and you have rootview mentioned in the component configuration there is an API to retrieve the root view

```
var comp = this.getOwnerComponent().getMetadata() // this is the view i am referring to here.
comp.getRootView()
```

You could write a recursively navigate this.parent() until you have the sViewName equal to the comp.getRootView(). 
This entry gets the rootview you are looking for and then sId gets you the ID which you can use to append.

I am not sure what you are trying to achieve but this is a hack i thought you can use to derive the rootview's ID.

Alternatively you can also specify the rootView ID while defining component something like this

```
rootView: {
            viewName : "ui.sample.demo.view.App",
            id : "Root",
            type : "XML"
        },
```

Comment: That was the missing bit. Thanks.